# How to access the field of a foreign table in Laravel 5?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, laravel

I am retrieving values of a foreign table in my CRUD. I have a tickets table with a ticket status. The tickets table has foreign_key of **ticket_statuses** table.

**TicketsController.php**

```
public function create()
{
    $users = User::all();
    $ticketstatus = TicketStatus::all();
    $tickets = Ticket::paginate(25);
    return View::make('user.tickets.create', compact('users','ticketstatus','tickets'));
}
```

**create.blade.php**

```
<div class="form-group">

    {!! Form::label('status', 'Status', ['class' => 'col-md-4 control-label']) !!}

    <div class="col-md-6">

        <select class="form-control form-field-ticket form-field-users">
            @foreach($tickets as $item)
                <option value="">{{$item->ticketstatus->status}}</option>
            @endforeach 
        </select>

    </div>                    

</div>
```

**Ticket.php**

```
public function ticketstatus()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\TicketStatus', 'ticket_status_id', 'id');
}
```

**TicketStatus.php**

```
// Ticket Status __has_many__ Ticket
public function tickets()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Ticket');
}
```

.

```
@foreach($tickets as $item)
    <option value="">{{$item->ticketstatus->status}}</option>
@endforeach
```

Thew code above gives the field of **tickets table**.

I want to access the **$item->ticketstatus->status of ticket_statuses** field of **ticket_statuses** table.

What do i need to do to be able to access that field? Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: @AmitGupta i am not getting any error. it's just that i am getting the wrong table and field

Comment: `$item->ticketstatus->id` gives the id of ticket_statuses table. w

Comment: @SanzeebAryal hmm.. $item->ticketstatus->id does not give the id of ticket_statues. it is from tickets table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think one ticket has only one status so, it is a one to one relationship.

In Ticket.php

```
public function ticket_status(){
    return $this->hasOne('App\TicketStatus','id','ticket_status_id');
}
```

Then,

```
    @foreach($tickets as $item)
        <option value="">{{$item->ticket_status->status}}</option>
    @endforeach
```